# Running Python script from a package... or not

Tags: python

So I have this little script that I want to run:

#### do_something.py

```py
from do_something import do_it

do_it()
```

Now this 'do_something' package has three files in it:

#### do_something/__init__.py

```py
from .things_to_do import do_it
```

#### do_something/things_to_do.py

```py
from .the_thing import the_thing

def do_it():
    print(f"Do it with {the_thing}")
```

#### do_something/the_thing.py

```py
the_thing = "The thing"
```

I can run my script with `python do_something.py` and I get the correct output.

```
Do it with The thing
```

Now what I need is being able to run the thing without the script, using `python do_something` (without the '.py' extension) *as well* as from the original .py script (for historical reasons).

So I created:

#### do_something/__main__.py

```py
from .things_to_do import do_it

do_it()
```

Unfortunately, this breaks in `__main__.py`, line 1:

```
    from .things_to_do import do_it
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

If I remove the '.' in the import directive, the error now appears in line 1 of `things_to_do.py`...

```
    from .the_thing import the_thing
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

How would you fix that code so that `python do_something` or `python do_something.py` are equivalent?

Thanks a lot!

Note: I also tried to mess with `sys.path` with very little success...

Answer (score 1):

the correct solution is to use `do_something.py` and run  `python -m do_something`, and have `do_something.py` directory on your `PYTHONPATH` or current directory.

the bad solution is to create a file `do_something` that has no extension next to your `do_something.py` and have the code inside `do_something` run your `do_something.py`.

```py
import runpy
import os
current_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
runpy.run_path(os.path.join(current_folder,"do_something.py"),run_name=__name__)
```

now this is a very bad design, and the proper way is to use python's `-m` arguments as in the first line of this answer, but this will just isolate the "corruption" to one file that has no logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick your answer!
Can you elaborate on why that would be "a very bad design"? I feel like this is very natural, and \_\_main\_\_.py would help...

Comment: @Primos this is no longer a python file, it's a text file, any linter/IDE won't identify it as a python file, and any test framework or package manager will fail to run it, github will require extra modifications to know its a code file and it's just bad all around ... this is not how python is made to work, and would be called "not pythonic" by any python coder.

Comment: @Primos also if this helped you be sure to mark it as the correct answer and upvoting is up to you.

Comment: Thanks again @ahmed-ask.

I really do understand that running one script from another wouldn't be a good idea.
That is not what I plan to do.

I'm just trying to avoid the `-m` option, and simply allow not to have to add the `.py` extension. In my opinion, that would be elegant, and \_\_main\_\_.py looks like the feature I need.
Anyway... if it's not possible, it is not.

As for the GitHub argument, I really don't get it. Everything is Python in my initial question, no confusion there.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Primos, it only makes sense to you, but anyone else working on the project or using it with any experience in python will complain, you can have `do_something` as a shell script and let it do `python -m do_something` if you want to omit the .py and -m in the shell.

Comment: It will not be pep compliant, it may not be portable to another python implementation ... There are a lot of problems in it.

Comment: Thanks again. The thing is I'm using Python to ensure portability so Shell is not an option. And I try to limit the number of entry points.

I understand I cannot do what I think would have been great for the end user, and that's fine. My original plan was not to explicitly have to use the -m option. You helped, I failed. And I don't really see the point the the \_\_main\_\_.py any longer...

Thanks again.